# Set state togglebutton with databinding

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms

I've got a form that contains a toggle button. To set the state of the togglebutton I use the property 'ToggleState' (which can be true or false).

I want to set the toggle button via databinding. I've pulled some data from a database and placed this in a listbox.
When selecting a item from the listbox all the other fields are populated with the corresponding data.
The only thing that's not set correctly is the toggle button.

Here is the code I have used to set the buttonstate via databinding. The buttonstate does not work.

```
ToggleButton1.DataBindings.Add("ToggleState", table, "Goedgekeurd", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
```

If I use the code below the buttonstate will set correctly.

```
ToggleButton1.ToggleState = 1
```

Can someone help me out what the difference is between the two?

Comment: I think that for the DataBinding to work properly, the class type for _`table`_ needs to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8). Can you let us know what type your variable `table` is, and its code if its a custom class please?

Comment: Hi, _table_ is declard as a datatable.
`Dim table As New DataTable()`

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work with a Table but I am having trouble understanding how you got it to work. Are you able to post a small working demo of what you are doing for me to replicate the problem?